# The laptop deadlocked after logging out from startx

Tags: enlightenment

I tried to first run Enlightenment Window Manager on tty2 after using the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> keystrokes. It ran normally but, afterwards, I opened a terminal in Enlightenment and typed `startx`. X11 also launched successfully. Then I logged out from `startx`. After showing that it logged out successfully, the notebook died.

I unplugged the machine anyway and tried to login again but was dead cycled at login page by asking me to type in the password forever, which is on tty7. I tried to run Enlightenment again on tty2 but it died halfway. I tried to tty3 this time and can still see everything in my laptop.

Should I `apt remove enlightenment` through tty3?

Comment: It is Xubuntu 20.04 LTS. I can still work on tty3 using text interface to access my file systems. Everything works except logging in to normal desktop. I was prompted to type in the password then jumped back to the login page repeatedly.

Comment: I tried the startx command again on tty2. It displayed "xauth: timeout in locking authority file /home/yiji/.Xauthority" then stopped responding. Afterwards, It printed a huge mass of misaligned error information on screen, "No protocal specified.." "xinit: unable to connect to X server: Resource temporarily unavailable" "waiting for X server to shutdown (II) Server teminated successfully (0). Closing log file." "xinit: server error" "xauth: timeout in locking authority file /home/yiji/.Xauthority".

Comment: I tried sudo Xorg -configure as well but it displays: "(EE) Fatal server error: (EE) Server is already active for display 0. If this server is no longer running, remove /tmp/.X0-lock and start again. (EE)" I tried on tty2 but I don't know what the 0 stands for in the message?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)

Comment: Thanks guiverc. My laptop became thoroughly dead, after I pressed the power button, it can no longer continue to the booting stage but kept blinking Capital and Screenshot keys. I know that is the end of my HP machine. In fact, since Dec 2020, I have reinstalled my Operating System 5 times, because the OS broke down= without any reason. I know my hardware is not healthy itself, as it has been used 5 years already.

Comment: I'm using a 2009 dell desktop, so 5 years old I don't consider old. If you used the power-button to force off (intentionally or accidental) without a clean shutdown (command into terminal, or via SysRq keys) I'd boot a *live* system (such as installation media) and perform quick checks, primarily `fsck` or file-system check (command or using GUI tool such as `gparted` or `gnome-disks`. Given your additional details I'd also check SMART health (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools) and likely do memtest overnight(s) to validate hardware (all from *live* media).  I'd do these first